# Подключение VK SDK для iOS к qt проекту

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, вконтакте

Qt-проект для ios и android. Нужно подключить VK SDK для ios.

- ВКонтакте о своей либе - https://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk
- Сама sdk для ios - https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk

Уже начал подключать VK SDK к проекту, просто разместив все исходники в новом модуле. Чтобы проект собрался, пришлось поискать, как включить ARC для *.mm файлов фрейворка

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -fobjc-arc
```

Предполагаю, что не всё гладко будет и с подключением ресурсов фреймворка. 
В этом пути не нравится, что готовый и правильно настроенный к сборке framework можно поломать, если не учесть какой-нибудь нюанс. И время это занимает не мало.

VK SDK библиотека - xcode проект. Собирается в `VkSdkFramework.framework`.
Можно ли подключить к Qt-проекту собранную `VkSdkFramework.framework`?

Если да, то нужно ли делать при сборке фреймворка *Code Signing* или можно оставить *Don't code Sign*? *Provisioning Profile* тут имеет значение? Релизы проекта подписываются фирменными сертификатами. Не будет ли конфликта с фреймфорком в плане *Code Sign*?

---

разместил собранную xCode `VkSdkFramework.framework` в проекте, подключил

```
LIBS += -framework VKSdkFramework
```

при сборке ошибка

```
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0
 and later (@rpath/VKSdkFramework.framework/VKSdkFramework)
 for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v
 to see invocation)
```

Comment: так вопрос можно ли подключить или почему ошибка?

Comment: Вопрос, как подключить, чтобы проект собирался с фрейморком. Ошибка, видимо, означает, что подключил библиотеку не так, как нужно.

Comment: нет, ошибка значит, что библиотека VK, которую вы используете не работает на iOS ниже 8го. либо ищите старую сборку, либо поднимайте deploy target до iOS8